# trying to count the charcters in a line in perl and failed

Tags: linux, perl, count, line, wc

At the beginning I simply used the following to count the length of each line:

```
while(<FH>){
    chomp;
    $length=length($_);
}
```

but when I compared the result I got with the one produced by linux command WC, I found a problem:
all tab characters in my file are treated as of `1 character` length in perl, whereas it is `8` for `wc`, so I did the following modification:

```
while(<FH>){
    chomp;
    my $length=length($_);
    my $tabCount= tr/\t/\t/;
    my $lineLength=$wc-$tabCount+($tabCount*8);
}
```

for the above code it works for all most all the cases now, except for one, in `wc` not all tabs are counted, but only the one that has not be taken with some characters, for example, if at the start of a line, I type in`1234`and then press a tab, in `wc` it is not counted as a tab, but the above code counted that, are there any ways I could adopt to solve this issue? Thanks

Solved it, used [tab expansion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-expand-tabs-in-a-string?), here is the code:

```
1 while $string =~ s/\t+/' ' x (length($&) * 8 - length($`) % 8)/e;
$length=length($string);
```

if anyone could give it an explanation, that would be awesome, I tested it to be working, but don't quite understand it. Anyways, thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, used [tab expansion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-expand-tabs-in-a-string?), here is the code:

```
1 while $string =~ s/\t+/' ' x (length($&) * 8 - length($`) % 8)/e;
$length=length($string);
```

if anyone could give it an explanation, that would be awesome, I tested it to be working, but don't quite understand it. Anyways, thanks for all the help

Answer (score 8):

I don't think tabs are your problem, **wc** doesn't count a tab as eight characters. I think your problem is that you're stripping EOLs but **wc** counts them. Also, you're not accumulating the lengths, you were just tracking the length of the last line. This:

```
while(<FH>){
    chomp;
    $length=length($_);
}
```

Should be more like this:

```
my $length = 0;
while(<FH>) {
    $length += length($_);
}
# $length now has the total number of characters
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just calling wc from within perl?

```
$result = `wc -l /path/to/file`
```

Comment: So, there is absolutely no way that I could solve this in perl?

Comment: I'm sure there is, you can do anything in perl :) if you can't call wc from perl then hopefully someone will post another solution for you

Comment: `wc -l` will count the number of lines, `wc -m` will count the number of characters.